# what does z subscript something mean

Tags: notation

Decide a positive integer $N \in\mathbb Z$. Generate a uniformly distributed random positive integer sequence:
$$v_1, v_2, \ldots,v_n\in\mathbb Z_N$$
My question is, what does $\mathbb Z_N$ really mean here?
Does it mean something like the set of integers up to $N$?

Comment: It totally depends upon context, but often $\mathbb Z_n$ refers to the integers modulo n.

Comment: Is it $\mathbb Z_N$? Then it should better be written $\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z$ to avoid confusion with certain other notations and refers to integers modulo $N$, which can be *represented* by the integers $0, 1, \ldots, N-1$.

Comment: okay!yes thank you so much.Got it, it is indeed integers modulo N,which would me the same set as integers less than N

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most often, one sees $\mathbb Z_n$ used to denote the **integers modulo $n$**, *represented* by $\mathbb Z_n = \{0, 1, 2, \cdots, n-1\}$: the *non-negative* integers less than $n$.  So this correlates with the set you discuss, in that we have a set of $n$ elements, but here, we start at $n = 0$ and increment until we reach $n - 1$, where we stop, (since $n \equiv 0\pmod n$).