# What does $\Bbb{Z}_N^\times$ mean?

Tags: notation

> We have $g^k = 1$ for every $g \in Z_N^\ast$, and therefore $g^{k/2}$ is a square root of unity modulo $N$.
> –[Dan Boneh, "Twenty Years of Attacks on the RSA Cryptosystem"](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Edabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf)

In this statement, what does $Z_N^\ast$ represent?

It's clear ([I think](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/382390/188128), but could be wrong,) that subscript-$N$ means that it's the integers *modulo* $N$, but it seems unlikely that the superscript asterisk has its usual meaning of "an infinite string of" in this context; I don't even have an idea of what to make of it.

(Per comments, it looks like this was, in part, a typesetting mistake—the author almost certainly *intended* to write $\Bbb{Z}_N^\times$—though the question remains essentially as-stated.)

Comment: I'm guessing it's used to refer to nonzero integers modulo $N$.

Comment: $\{1,2,3\cdots,N-1\}$, it refers to the invertible elements mod N

Comment: Given a ring $(R,+,\cdot)$, $R^*$ is the multiplicative group of its invertible elements (i.e. the elements $x\in R$ such that there is some $y\in R$ such that $xy=yx=1$). For $R=\Bbb Z_N$, you can equally take it as the set of the elements $x\in\{0,\cdots, N-1\}$ such that $\operatorname{gcd}(N,x)=1$ endowed with multiplication modulo $N$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Thanks for the edit suggestion, but [I think the author didn't use Blackboard typesetting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3jkc.png).

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude. I checked the [linked PDF](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Edabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf) and it uses $\Bbb Z$ (something like `\Bbb Z` in LaTeX speek).

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Per my screenshot, the bit I quoted _is_ typeset non-Blackboard, and that was part of the reason I lacked confidence in my interpretation of the symbol. I would welcome a criticism of Dan Boneh's inconsistency in an Answer, however, as he appears to use the Blackboard font for the same(?) symbol elsewhere in the document.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude: Ok, I didn't check each and every occurrence of "Z" in that document; sorry for the noise.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Honestly, it'd be great for an answer to nitpick the typesetting of the original document from a knowledgeable perspective -- the author's use of $\ast$ instead of $\times$ in that symbol was another obstacle to identifying it -- even if I'd stumbled across the appropriate Wikipedia page, I might have not matched it due to that.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude $R^*$ is just as common a notation as $R^\times$ for the group of units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_N^\times$ refers to the **multiplicative group of integers modulo $N$**.

In other words: those elements of ring $\mathbb{Z}_N$ which are invertible under $\times$.

In other words: the nonnegative integers less than $N$ which are coprime to $N$.

In other words: for prime $N$, $\mathbb{Z}_N \setminus {\{{0}\}}$ — the positive integers less than $N$.

---

Beware that some authors may use $\ast$ or $\cdot$ instead of $\times$!